# Can the preposition "over" be used to describe what we are doing a project on?

Tags: prepositions

What did I actually choose to do my personal project over?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it, it might be understood, but it does not sound *natural*.
As the headline to your questions indicates "***on***" is the correct preposition.

You run the risk that

> **do my personal project over**

would be interpreted as you are *redoing* your personal project since the first attempt was not successful.